# Turn TV into large digital photo frame through the HDMI port

Tags: video, photography, video-player

I would like to turn my TVs into large photo frames that shows my pictures and/or plays my videos when I'm not using the TVs otherwise.

I need:

- The files to be read from a PC / NAS / external hard drive.
- An easy setup with a random or by date interval display of files.

It should be powered by an app running on an Android phone or on an Apple iPhone / iPad / Apple TV or alternatively on a computer connected to the TV through HDMI, USB or similar.

Ideally I would like to use my Apple TV (4th gen) connected to my TV to get the files from a Windows 10 computer through my network and display them on the TVs.

Alternatively I could connect my old Samsung S7 or iPhone 7 to my TVs and use them to get the files from a Windows 10 computer or a NAS.

Any solution that can turn all my TVs into large photo frames and that can get the files it has to display from a PC or NAS on my local network would do.

I don't know if Plex (https://www.plex.tv/your-media/) is a solution that will work or not.

Any tips anyone?

Comment: What is the operating system of the TV you have? Or what protocol is usable to display content on it?

Comment: It should work with any TV regardless of its operating system. The best would be to use HDMI to display the content.

Comment: Why the downvote on this good question?

Answer (score 1):

The TV part is easy - just connect it to a device that has HDMI output and can connect to and read from the NAS and the switch the TV input to HDMI. Personally I would suggest a Raspberry PiZero W - HDMI output & WiFi + Bluetooth:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/

[image: Raspberry PiZero W]

Even with a case you are looking under £20.

Then you are just looking for a slideshow application that can run on the PiZero - A google search gave over a million results but [this article](https://www.instructables.com/id/Easy-Raspberry-Pi-Based-ScreensaverSlideshow-for-E/) gives one set of options or [slide-pi-stretch](https://github.com/NautiluX/slide) could be a nice option. *Note that both the above assume a Pi 3 but should run OK on Zero*.

If you are looking to customise the selection rules then [py-slideshow](https://github.com/cgoldberg/py-slideshow) could be a good starting point.

Of course you could also look at a sligthly more powerful Pi running [RasPlex](https://www.rasplex.com/).